# The set of accumulation points is open

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the Identity Theorem, as follows:

We have an holomorphic function $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ where $D$ is connected. If $A=\{z:f(z)=0\}$ has an accumulation point, then $f(z)=0$ for each $z\in D$.

I want to prove that if $A'$ is the set of accumulation point of $A$, then $A'$ is open and closed in $D$. It is clear it's closed, but why it's open?

Is there an elementary proof of that set is open? (I can't use Taylor's Theorem yet...)

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this before showing that holomorphic functions have (convergent) power series expansions? The most natural approach is via power series.

Comment: @mrf Because I need to use the Identity Theorem but I can't use power series yet. Thanks for your comment.